# Integer not passing as reference to a function in Swift

Tags: c, swift, pointers, opengl

I'm trying to use a C library with Swift. I'm using a C function, and a parameter required appeared to be a pointer. But it's giving the error that the type is invalid.

Here's the code:

```
    let shaderString = tempShaderString! as NSString
    let shaderCString = shaderString.UTF8String as UnsafePointer<GLchar>
    var shaderStringLength = GLint(shaderString.length)

    shaderHandle = glCreateShader(GLenum(type))
    glShaderSource(shaderHandle, 1, shaderCString, &shaderStringLength)
```

I get this error:

```
Cannot invoke glShaderSource with an argument list of type '(GLuint)', Int, UnsafePointer<GLchar>, inout Int32.
```

Note that `GLint` is an `Int32` in Xcode.

Comment: what swift type does `GLsizei` map to?

Comment: GLSize is most likely CGFloat

Comment: `glsizei` is a typedef for `int` so I guess it won't be a a `CGFloat`. It shouldn't be any special type from Core Graphics. I would assume it to be an `Int`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In C the function parameters are defined as

```
(GLuint shader, GLsizei count, const GLchar **string, const GLint *length)
```

I would assume there will be a problem with the 3rd parameter (`string`). Maybe you should also pass it with an `&` to get the double reference.

Note that:

> **string**
>   Specifies an **array** of pointers to strings containing the source
>   code to be loaded into the shader.

Comment: Thanks. It worked when I did that, and changed the declaration of the C string to be a mutable 'var'.